# `npm list`, it doesn't show `create-react-app`

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

a quick and probably a silly question but really couldn't find the answer. So ok, I have already installed [`\[create-react-app\]`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) via `npm`, but when i use `npm list`, it doesn't show me that, why? what would be the command-line that shows everything that I have used `npm` to install?

Comment: if you installed it globally and just created a project with it it's just going to add react-scripts as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the save option when you installed?

```
npm install create-react-app --save
```

It's possible that you npm installed it somewhere different than where you are calling npm list. In that case try:

```
npm list -g
```

Depending on user you may have to sudo those commands on Linux.

Comment: @ILoveReactAndNode, I added another method to look at all globally installed packages, that may work if its a location issue